# Jmeter Summary Report does not show the "90% Line" colmun

Tags: jmeter

I made a Jmeter Test, and add Summary Report as Listener for the test results, but it does not show me the "90% Line" colmun..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener in order to see the [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile), by default you have 3 pre-defined ones:

- 90%
- 95%
- 99%

You can even control the values by modifying the following [JMeter properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
aggregate_rpt_pct3=99
```

[image: Aggregate Report]

---

Be aware that you should be using JMeter Listeners only for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to running your test make sure you remove or disable all the listeners as they can be resource intensive and even may ruin your test. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)

So you need to run test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and after test finishes open .jtl results file with the listener(s) of your choice and analyze it. You can also generate a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the .jtl results file.

Comment: I've created a function in the Aggregate Report, so the results can be saved in the file with this function : "${runTestsDir}/${TestName}/aggregat_report_${__time(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss)}.jtl", and I runmy test, but in the file system, the file hat not been created....does someone know why?